# Webpack and Modules

Tags: webpack, module

I have a module.js file like this:

```
...
export { run };
```

And I implement it in my HTML File like this:

```
import * as Something from './src/module.js'; 
Something.run();
```

So far so good... **It will work.** 
But once I bundle it with Webpack v4 and put the source into the from Statement **it will fail**. It looks like webpack removes my export. Need help!

*Edit*:
weppack.config.js

```
const path = require('path');
module.exports = {
    entry: './src/module.js',
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
        filename: 'bundle.js'
    },
    module: {
        rules: [{
            test: /\.js?$/,
            exclude: /node_modules/,
            use: {
                loader: 'babel-loader',
                options: {
                    presets: ['@babel/preset-env']
                }
            }
        }]
    }
};
```

Comment: put babel and webpack config

Comment: config is in the thread now